# Tkinter - Cannot figure out why data is being entered simultaneously in 2 entry boxes

Tags: tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and currently writing a code to display sum of 2 numbers on a third text field. But when I type in an integer value in the text box 1, it simultaneously types in the same value in text box 2 too. 
Apparently, both of them are being stored in the same variable. 
The code is here :

```
def showSum(fnum,lnum):
try:
    some_var = int(fnum)
except ValueError:
    print("Error. Not an integer number!")
try:
    some_var = int(lnum)
except ValueError:
    print("Error. Not an integer number!")
sum = fnum+lnum
sum_label['text'] = str(sum)


FirstNumLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="Enter Num 1: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
FirstNum = 0
FirstNumEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=FirstNum).grid(row=0, column=1)

LastNumLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="Enter Num 2: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
LastNum = 0
LastNumEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=LastNum).grid(row=1, column=1)

showSum = partial(showSum, FirstNum, LastNum)
showButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Show", command=showSum).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

So when I try to enter first number, it automatically enters same number in second number text box too. And vice versa.

Moreover, the sum function displays 0 as the sum to the above integers.

I have tried searching it on Google but have not found any solution to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `textvariable` option must use one of the special tkinter variables `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `BooleanVar`, or `DoubleVar`. `StingVar` is by far the most common.

Because you are using an integer, both entry widgets have their `textvariable` set to `0`. This creates an internal variable named `0` which is updated whenever the widget value changes. Since they share the same internal variable, they both share the same value.